# Changing Titles on R PDF

Tags: r

I am currently using a for loop to create a multiple page pdf in R. It is working to create the pages with the different values for everything except the title. How do I get it to change the title from page to page.

```
pdf("dt.pdf")
ct <- vector(mode="list", length(many.frames))
for(m in 1:length(many.frames)){
ct[[m]] <- qcc(many.frames[[m]]$dt, sizes=many.frames[[m]]$td, confidence.level = .95, type='p',
title="P Chart for DT
 for hdn[m]")
}
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `paste` function to join strings and variables.

```
..., title = paste("P Chart for DT for", hdn[m]))
```